# Should I use ExitThread() or Return from threads in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, winsock2

I'm developing a server app to which multiple clients will connect. For every new client, I create a new thread and want to free all the resources of each client once the client disconnect.

My main thread doesn't need return values from client(s) so I just want to safely terminate threads and deallocate the resources uses by/in the thread.

What should I use in this case and why ?

Comment: You should use `return`, so that the C++ library gets to call all the appropriate destructors.

Comment: How did you create the thread ?

Comment: @RichardCritten It doesn't make any difference how the thread was created. If there are objects on the stack they will only be destructed if C++ knows about the exit.

Comment: @user207421 sometimes the start a thread and finish a thread API calls need to match (platform specific obviously).

Comment: `ExitThread` is not part of standard C++. If you're writing portable code (and you should be), use `return`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Does this answer your question? Sometimes it is very useful to read the reference:

[ExitThread](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-exitthread)

> Remarks
>
> ExitThread is the preferred method of exiting a thread in C code. However, in C++ code, the thread is exited before any destructors can be called or any other automatic cleanup can be performed. Therefore, in C++ code, you should return from your thread function.

Comment: VG but I'm curious why `ExitThread()` was ever preferred in C.

Comment: @user207421 A good question, the only reason i can think of would be to 'terminate` the thread from any function outside of the thread starting function, where a return would simply return from that specific function rather than terminating the thread.

Comment: Thanks Erdal , I had actually read the reference but wasn't sure whether i should use return because I do not need to return something from threads.

Comment: @user260854 `ExitThread` allows to return a failure exit code from a thread. So it can be useful for abnormal returns. Returning from a thread function always returns the exit code 0.

Comment: The quote about `ExitThread` being the preferred method in C is a bit misleading, as it contradicts the following information, which is also on the page you linked to: "A thread in an executable that is linked to the static C run-time library (CRT) should use _beginthread and _endthread for thread management rather than CreateThread and ExitThread. Failure to do so results in small memory leaks when the thread calls ExitThread."

Comment: @rustyx "*Returning from a thread function always returns the exit code 0.*" - that depends on the thread API used. If you use `CreateThread()` , `_beginthreadex()`, `pthread_create()`, etc, then the thread function can simply `return` an exit code/value. But, if you use `_beginthread()`, `std::thread`, etc instead, then that is not an option.